# Worklight security remote server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

My Worklight project use the security module and WorkLightAuthenticator WorkLightAuthLoginModule. When I run the application on environment 
development, it works perfectly. When I import the project to the remote server, it seems that do not find the WorkLightAuthenticator. 
To import to the remote server, I need to do something besides include the .adapter and .wlapp the Worklight Console?

Changes made in authenticationConfig.xml on eclipse comes with these files (. and adapter. wlapp), or need to do manually on the remote server?

Comment: Is this question resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Changes made to the authenticationConfig.xml file are saved in the `bin\<projectName>.war` file. You **must** re-deploy this .war file.

See this IBM Worklight Information Center topic: [Deploying IBM Worklight applications to test and production environments](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/t_transporting_apps_and_adapters.html)

Also see this training module for an overview [about the process of moving to production](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/10_01_Moving_from_development_environment_to_stand-alone_QA_and_production_servers.pdf) (which also provides a general overview of a Worklight project)